# Show soft keyboard with adjust pane

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for my `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest` and want to show the keyboard programmatically after adding an `EditText` to a `Fragment` in my `Activity`. Whatever method I try to show the keyboard, it ignores the `"adjustPan"` setting and resizes my layout.

How can I programmatically show the keyboard while respecting the `"adjustPan"` setting?

Comment: Have you tried setting `adjustPan|adjustResize`?

Comment: @ReazMurshed Just tried it and it behaves like `adjustNothing` although I have no idea why. But doesn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

2 years late, but if someone else got the same problem.

Use:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```